# Rails ActionMailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, helper, contact-form, autoload

so I am trying to build a simple website for a friend who has a startup for android apps that they build for clients. I am building it in RoR and am pretty new to this kind of development. I'm working on the contact us form. I already have the Message model done and recently generated the mailer helper for the model. Running into this error: Unable to autoload constant MessageMailer, expected /home/dmberko11/web_development/NovayTechnologies/NovayTechnologiesWebsite/app/mailers/message_mailer.rb to define it

Very confused as to why that is. I'll paste my code for what I have so far:

message_mailer.rb

```
class MessageMailer < ApplicationMailer

  # Subject can be set in your I18n file at config/locales/en.yml
  # with the following lookup:
  #
  #   en.message_mailer.contact_me.subject
  #
  def contact_me(message)
     @body = message.body

     mail to: "davidmichaelberko@gmail.com", from: message.email
  end
end
```

**the messages controller:**

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController

 def create
  @message = Message.new(message_params)
  if @message.valid?
   MessageMailer.contact_me(@message).deliver_now
   redirect_to root_path, notice: "Message received"
  else render 'new'
 end
end
```

**message model**

```
class Message < ApplicationRecord

  attr_accessor :name, :email, :body
  validates :name, :email, :body, presence: true 
end
```

Again, I'm a mewb when it comes to web development but this friend of mine is being extremely patient with me and he wants me to succeed on this website I'm trying to build for him. I used to do this stuff years ago but I'm super rusty and have to relearn everything. Any and all help is welcome! Thanks and have a great day

Comment: is the code in `message_mailer.rb` the one you have in your project ?, is that it ?. There seem to be two `contact_me` methods, one inside the other, and it looks like there's a missing `end` ?

Comment: @gasc you were right about the two methods. I think when I generated the message mailer it automatically had a contact_me method but I redefined it and consequently declared def contact_me(message) a second time by accident. Whoops. Glad it was a silly mistake. Thanks for the answers everyone. I love stack overflow and hope to one day be knowledgeable enough to contribute. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You have to put `message_mailer.rb` inside the proper folder:

`app/mailers/message_mailer.rb`

restart your server.

Comment: Good thought, as the constants are autoloaded from the parent /app directory however I already have that file nested in the mailers folder like you suggested. It's something else that's causing the error. Real head scratcher

Comment: @dmberko11 Try again, paste all the code. That error you posted is 100% for a missing file or typo or the file is somehow not defined. I have been doing this for too long, and see that error dozens of times.

Comment: someone else pointed out to me that I accidentally was defining the contact_me method twice in the message_mailer.rb file. When I generated the mailer for messages it automatically created the method and for whatever reason when I went in to modify the method I wrote the def contact_me(message) line twice, lol. Rook mistake. Blame it on sleep deprivation. I do have another question I'm going to post though, maybe you can help me with it! I'm trying to initialize the javascript for tinymce_editor for a text_area in a form for creating posts and it's not working....